# ScheduledExecutorService call shutdown for infinite scheduling

Tags: java, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I am using a ScheduledExecutorService that would be scheduled to run every minute infinitely

Could some one tell me when to invoke the shutdown on the ScheduledExecutorService

I have already looked into Guava MoreExecutors. This does not work as I need to block the main thread to keep the other threads running continuously

**Use case**

I have a task that constantly monitors a system to check for latency/failures.

I need to run this task periodically and configure Cloudwatch alarms based on it. Ideally, I would want the task to continue executing even when there is a latency spike, because the alarm would have been triggered

So, I am using a ScheduledExecutorService to periodically schedule the tasks.

I want to know the ideal place where I would call shutdown() on the executor service

Comment: i will recommended to explain use case

Comment: @Deadpool I have updated the use case

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the factory methods in `Executors` return an instance of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`<sup>1</sup>. By default, a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` will not continue executing periodic tasks after it has been shutdown. You can configure this via [`setContinueExistingPeriodicTasksAfterShutdownPolicy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#setContinueExistingPeriodicTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(boolean)).

> Sets the policy on whether to continue executing existing periodic tasks even when this executor has been `shutdown`. In this case, executions will continue until `shutdownNow` or the policy is set to `false` when already shutdown. This value is by default `false`.

As it's really an implementation detail what implementation of `ScheduledExecutorService` the factory methods of `Executors` return, it's probably better to create a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` directly.

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
executor.setContinueExistingPeriodicTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(true);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> System.out.println("Hello, World!"), 0L, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
executor.shutdown();
```

Note, this currently configures the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to use *non-daemon* threads. Even though `shutdown` was called, if the periodic tasks aren't cancelled they will keep the JVM alive. Use a custom `ThreadFactory` if you want to use daemon threads.

---

<sup>1. The `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor` methods return a *non-configurable wrapper* that delegates to a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.</sup>